# SAS Error Handling - Check after a data step to see if error was thrown

Tags: oracle, error-handling, sas

Hi I have a SAS job that runs successfully 90% of the time. But one of the steps relies on reading an oracle table that is occasionally being updated at the same time as I'm trying to read it. I implemented a check to see if it exists first before querying it, but since the pull takes ~15 minutes, it will sometimes exist at the start of the pull but not by the end which results in a SAS error.

What I want to do is gracefully catch this error, sleep for x time, and then attempt to re-run the same pull without the SAS job failing. Is there a way to do this in SAS? All the things I've searched rely on checking pre-conditions before the pull, but what can I do when those can change during the pull leading to an error?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can truly catch the error (meaning prevent it from reaching the log), but once the error has been thrown you can detect it, sleep, and try again, and may even be able to reset job return codes etc.  Can you show sample code for how you are reading the Oracle data (data step or SQL step etc) and what error is thrown?

Comment: How are you running this job?  Batch?  Scheduled through EG?  Scheduled through SAS Schedule Manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a bunch of different ways, but I think the old school method is probably best.

Assuming you're running this in batch mode - split your oracle pull into its own program, and call that program with its own call to SAS.exe.  Have it put out a value (touch a file, say, or write the date or something to a file) and have the batch program look for that file/value.  When that file/value is updated, then the batch program moves onto the rest of the process; if it's not updated, then sleep and re-call that program.

If you're doing this in Enterprise Guide, it's a bit easier as you can have a condition that does more or less the same thing (but you can actually check for error conditions via macro variables).  You would need to not have SAS set to ABEND on an error, though.

Comment: If you run the sub program with SYSTASK you can retrieve the job status code through a macro variable.

Comment: @data_null_ Good point, though I'm not sure I know enough about SYSTASK to explain that in an answer.  If you want to either put that in your own answer or edit it into mine please feel free.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach that might be worth trying: if your oracle database will allow you to lock tables via SAS, try running a `lock` statement immediately before the data step. You can then check the result of the lock attempt via the `&SYSLCKRC` automatic macro variable, wait, and try again.

E.g.

```
%macro wait_for_lock(DATASET);
  %let MINUTES_WAITED = 0;
  %do %until(&SYSLCKRC = 0 or &MINUTES_WAITED > 60);
    lock &DATASET;
    %if &SYSLCKRC ne 0 %then %do;
      data _null_;
        sleep = sleep(60);
      run;
    %end;
    %let MINUTES_WAITED = %eval(&MINUTES_WAITED + 1);
  %end;
%mend;

%wait_for_lock(oraclelib.mytable);
```

You can also use the [FILEOCKWAIT](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/FILELOCKWAIT_libname_option) system option to accomplish the same thing in more recent versions of SAS than the ancient one that I'm used to.

Comment: Don't forget to unlock it ;-)